# How can make chart starts from centerline of chart plot at Highchart js?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using areaspline chart type at highchart. My series that i haved used in this chart is defined as follows:

```
var data = [{ datetime: '08:35', value: '2087696.02'},
{datetime: '08:40', value: '2087696.02'},
{ datetime: '08:45', value: '2087696.02'},
{datetime: '08:50', value: '2087696.02'},
{datetime: '08:55', value: '2087696.02},
{datetime: '09:00', value: '2087696.02},
{datetime: '09:05', value: '2088225.04'},
{datetime: '09:25', value: '2088505.21'}]
```

How can make the chart starts from centerline of chart plot?

Comment: Hi @amir tbi, Could you describe more clearly what result you want to achieve? Here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fqtn0do3/ is reproduced current stage.

Comment: @ppotaczek, Thanks for reproducing, I am looking for to make chart starts from a point that belongs to last day ,for example.  And this point  should be placed at the center of plot.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not entirely sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to show the first point in the middle of the chart, similar to here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9uk4sf3w/

Comment: @ppotaczek, The first point should be placed at the center of max and min values of yAxis. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tickPositioner` function and calculate the positions of y-axis ticks as you want. For example:

```
  yAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function() {
      const yAxis = this;
      const series = yAxis.series;
      const center = series[0].processedYData[0];
      const minDiff = Math.abs(yAxis.min - center);
      const maxDiff = Math.abs(yAxis.max - center);
      const tickPositions = [];
      let interval;

      if (minDiff > maxDiff) {
        interval = minDiff / 3;
      } else {
        interval = maxDiff / 3;
      }

      for (let i = center - interval * 3; i <= center + interval * 3; i += interval) {
        tickPositions.push(+i.toFixed(2));
      }

      return tickPositions;
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/79f3onq4/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner